# What is an expression for finishing up work on a newspaper/magazine issue?

Tags: terminology, phrase-requests, business-language

Suppose your team is working on a newspaper issue of which the deadline is approaching. Therefore, final touches must be put to it before sending it to the printers. What expression do you use to express this?

Is this right?

> Today we are closing the (February) issue.

Comment: A usual term in the US is "putting it to bed". Like a child. You pull the covers up and walk away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an idiom or phrase set for completing a task, or completion of an event?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284186/is-there-an-idiom-or-phrase-set-for-completing-a-task-or-completion-of-an-event)

Comment: I don't think it does. What I am looking for is (probably) a journalistic jargon, an expression specific to that profession.

Comment: Are you doing the printing  in-house, or sending it out?

Comment: Sending it out. Why? Does the expression depend on it?

Comment: @JohnLawler I thought that "putting the paper to bed" originally referred to passing the copy over to the typesetters who would then get the type ready to be placed on the bed of the press. In other words the copy preparation process was complete and only "stop press" items could be added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do want to sound like a professional?

[***put the paper to bed***](https://nieonline.com/coloradonie/downloads/journalism/GlossaryOfNewspaperTerms.pdf)

..is the time-honored phrase in use since at least the turn of the previous century.

> When  the  paper heads to press and newsroom has signed off all pages.

That said, and paraphrasing...

> "Today we are putting  the (February) issue to bed."

...sounds better. A professional would understand that there is a *deadline*.

---

I can personally attest that this is the journalistic jargon.
I worked at a major up-state NY Daily tabloid  in distribution, editorial, and graphics  in the US during the 1970s-1980s; we printed in-house the morning edition.

We had a soft-8 hard-10 p.m. deadline for turning in composited stories. There was a little more leeway for graphics and cutlines.

However, I also did some work on weeklies and monthlies, and those we sent out to local printers capable of handling tabloid..

The publishers of those were often ignorant as to the real terminology. It was quite some work to introduce jargon to people like that.

If they do not understand that, just say

> We are wrapping it up i.e. "It's a wrap".

Younger people seem to get the cine jargon better...

Comment: There is nothing more intoxicating for a young journalist than seeing their words and photos being published 300,000 times in early, late, and city edition, and pulling that piece off the run in the midst of the rolling  impact of the 2 story high presses...I used to wait up until 2 in the morning on Sundays, and 4 a.m. on major stories... Good memories.

Comment: Great, thank you. And you're right about watching the presses... Is "putting to bed" used in British English, too?

Comment: @strah It certainly is.